What is the rigorous definition of "x is in the top N elements of linear order L"?
Suppose we are given a finite linear order $L$, and an element $x \in L$. What is the rigorous definition of "$x$ is in the top $N$ elements of the linear order". The reason I am asking is because, to give an example, suppose $x$ is in the third position of the linear order, but $L$ has only $4$ elements. Would it still be true to say $x$ is in the top $5$ elements? I think it wouldn't, but then we would have the semi-paradoxical situation where $x$ is in the top $3$ but not the top $5$. So, that is why I want a rigorous definition.

It means whatever you define it to mean. One reasonable definition would be "the set of upper bounds of $x$ in $L$ has cardinality at most $N$": $|{y \in L \mid x ≤ y}| ≤ N$.

@NaïmFavier, I suggest that you make this an answer.

One reasonable definition would be "the set of upper bounds of $x$ in $L$ has cardinality at most $N$", that is
$$|\{y \in L \mid x \leq y \}| \leq N$$
Note that this does not assume that the "top $N$" set of elements contains $N$ elements. It is common in mathematics to make as few assumptions as necessary, even if this goes against everyday intuition.

Yes, for a mathematician, a proposition like

The number $7$ is one of the $100$ largest in the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, 10\}$

is considered (vacuously) true.
